# JTable and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jtable

I am using JTable. Many threads will try to add rows to the JTable.

Problem : Only one row gets added. After that, no row gets added.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to update the jtable? are you using SwingUtilities?

Answer (score 2):

Swing is generally not thread-safe. If you need to modify Swing components from Threads other than the AWT Event-dispatch-Thread, use

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run() {
   // here your modification code
}});
```

Alternatively `invokeAndWait`. (These methods in fact do the same as the like-named methods in `java.awt.EventQueue`.)

Answer (score 0):

> Only one row gets added. After that, no row gets added.

Probably because you recreate the TableModel every time, or you have multiple references to the TableModel and your code is updating the wrong model.